# How to process elements of an array serially in node-red?

Tags: arrays, asynchronous, node-red

Here is the scenario -

1. In flow1 we run a sql query to retrieve some rows ordered by timestamp
2. Flow2 defines a sequence of API calls , so this flow executes asynchronously
3. For each result in flow1 , we need to invoke flow2 "synchronously" , i.e next element should be processed only when execution of flow2 has comepleted for previous element

With the split and join solution, the order can not be guaranteed.

What could be the simplest way to handle this scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

This worked in the above scenario -

https://discourse.nodered.org/t/how-to-process-elements-of-an-array-serially-in-node-red/13997/6?u=jsmith